# ¿como resolver el error?: AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'tslib'

Tags: python-3.7, rstudio

El problema es relacionado al siguiente código:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import pandas as pd
from ggplot import diamonds

matplotlib.style.use("ggplot")

AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'tslib'

Detailed traceback: 
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/rstudio-user/.local/share/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ggplot/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from .geoms import geom_area, geom_blank, geom_boxplot, geom_line, geom_point, geom_jitter, geom_histogram, geom_density, geom_hline, geom_vline, geom_bar, geom_abline, geom_tile, geom_rect, geom_bin2d, geom_step, geom_text, geom_path, geom_ribbon, geom_now_its_art, geom_violin, geom_errorbar, geom_polygon
  File "/home/rstudio-user/.local/share/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ggplot/geoms/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .geom_abline import geom_abline
  File "/home/rstudio-user/.local/share/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ggplot/geoms/geom_abline.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .geom import geom
  File "/home/rstudio-user/.local/share/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ggplot/geoms/geom.py", line 3, in <module>
    from ..ggplot import ggplot
  File "/home/rstudio-user/.local/share/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ggplot/ggplot.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .aes import aes
  File "/home/rstudio-user/.local/share/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ggplot/aes.py", line 11, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "/home/rstudio-user/.local/share/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ggplot/utils.py", line 81, in <module>
    pd.tslib.Timestamp,
```

Quiero utilizar ggplot para importar el dataset diamonds en **RStudio cloud** utilizando Miniconda pero no puedo ya que me sale el error que puse en el titulo de la pregunta. ¿Como podría solucionarlo?.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow en Español, te recomiendo puedas colocar un codigo con el error reproducible o ser más especifico para saber donde tienes el problema.

Comment: Te recomiendo poner el error log **completo** en **texto/código**. ://

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema radica en que hay un error al momento de importar las librerías tal vez por cuestión de versiones diferentes, existe un issue en github sobre este problema justamente; aparentemente es posible solucionarlo modificando el archivo: `ggplot/utils.py`, en tu caso esta en :

```
/home/rstudio-user/.local/share/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ggplot/utils.py
```

Sugieren modificar

```
date_types = (
    pd.tslib.Timestamp,
    pd.DatetimeIndex,
    pd.Period,
    pd.PeriodIndex,
    datetime.datetime,
    datetime.time
)
```

Para que funcione básicamente deberías eliminar el uso de tslib quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
date_types = (
    pd.Timestamp,
    pd.DatetimeIndex,
    pd.Period,
    pd.PeriodIndex,
    datetime.datetime,
    datetime.time
)
```

Es posible que ahora la raíz de tu error te la marque en el archivo `ggplot/stats/smoothers.py`, por lo que debes hacer lo mismo en ese archivo. y comentar el import del timestamp:

```
from pandas.lib import Timestamp
```

---

Sí eso no funciona en otro caso también podría funcionar haciendo un downgrade a la versión de pandas a la 0.19.2 con:

```
!pip install pandas==0.19.2
```

Espero te sea útil.

Comment: No me funciono haciendo el  downgrade. Pero en el primer caso, como haces la modificación, ya que haciendo la chunk en R o python para modificar utilizando el **date_type** no funciona, me dice: `NameError: name 'datetime' is not defined
Detailed traceback: 
  File "<string>", line 6, in <module>`

Comment: Podrías indicar el archivo dónde obtienes el error.?

Comment: Ya lo modifique, no sabia donde como hacer la modificación pero ya lo pude hacer gracias.

Comment: `ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1: version ``ZLIB_1.2.9' not found (required by /home/rstudio-user/.local/share/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/../../.././libpng16.so.16)
Detailed traceback: 
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/rstudio-user/.local/share/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 207, in <module>
    _check_versions()
  File "/home/rstudio-user/.local/share/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py"
    from import ft2font``

Comment: Básicamente serian los mismos directorios pero en: matplotlib/__init__.py, parte 207 y 192 de la linea de código creo que seria el último problema.